# Which exceptions to handle while making a remote call in Java

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I am making a remote call in my application. I want to handle different exceptions and perform different tasks in case of respective exceptions.

I am looking into `MalformedURLException` , `UnknownHostException`, `ConnectionException` and `SocketTimeoutException`.

I know that in case of `MalformedURLException` I want to drop the request and this one is fairly simple.

```
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    log.info("MalformedURLException while fetching log");
    log.info("Content Url is Invalid and is being Dropped");
    return keywords;
}
```

Now In case of **internet disconnection** I want to retry the request after a small interval. Here which exception should I handle?

I am confused between `ConnectException` and `UnknownHostException`.

```
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    log.info("UnknownHostException while fetching log");
    log.info("Internet disconnectivity Retrying Content Url");
    keywords.add(value);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return keywords;
}
```

Next I am using `con.setConnectTimeout(20000);` and `con.setReadTimeout(30000);` in my code. So I am guessing if this expires then I can handle `SocketTimeoutException`?

```
catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    log.info("SocketTimeoutException while fetching log:");
    keywords = increaseRetryCount(keywords, result, retryCount, url);
    return keywords;
}
```

Am I approaching the problem correctly and using the right exceptions? Kindly tell me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectException` and `UnknownHostException` can occur both when there is no connection. `UnknownHostException` occurs when there was no entry at the DNS Cache and `ConnectException` when there was an entry at the DNS Cache but the host was not reachable.

Simply catch `IOException` and retry (but not forever, instead increase the pauses and give up after some time).

The only special case would be an invalid URL or an permanent error from the server (like invalid authentication, ...).

Comment: But `IOException` can occur for a lot of reasons. I want to handle a general exception like `IOException` or just `Exception` to do a different task. So should I handle `IOException` for both `ConnectException` and `UnknownHostException` and then catch `Exception` for a more general handling? What do you suggest?